# Flask/Python - How can I run this python script in Flask and render output in html page

Tags: python, html, flask, heroku, render

Im writting this code to get some values of stock prices, and how can I render output results in results.html page?
I'm using Heroku to make this app.

Please help me with this app.
This is the main file to call others files.

Please tell me if need more details to run this app.

Here are the codes I've made, to display the output in view.html page.
x.py

```py
print('----EURO DO REMESSA ONLINE-----')
import melhor
print('-----COTAÇÃO DOLARHOJE.COM-----')
import cota
print('-----INDICADOR EURO COMERCIAL H1----')
import indicator
print('-----INVESTING VALOR EURO COM-----')
import invest
print( '-------------\n', 'Conhece a ti mesmo. (Tales de Mileto)', '\n-------------')
```

---

melhor.py

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time
import re
from Color import *
url = 'https://www.remessaonline.com.br/cotacao/cotacao-euro'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
page
page.status_code
page.text
soup = bs(page.text, 'html.parser')
resumo = soup.find_all('div', class_="style__Text-sc-27fg4f-2 ddwOcG")[0].get_text('')
mult = float(re.sub('[^0-9.]', "", resumo.replace(",",".")))
print('Euro COMERCIAL: R$', Base.BOLD, ANSI_Compatible.Color(120), mult, ANSI_Compatible.END, Base.END)
eur_rate = 1.035145
eur_ra = str(mult * eur_rate)[:6]
print('Euro TURISMO: R$', Base.BOLD, eur_ra, Base.END)
current = time.strftime("%Y / dia:%d mês:%m horário:%H:%M:%S")
print(current)
with open('remessa.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.writelines('Valor euro turismo:' + 'R$' + eur_ra + ' ' + 'Data:' + current + '\n')
```

---

cota.py

```py
import requests
import time

response = requests.get('http://dolarhoje.com/cotacao.txt')
data = response.text
print('1 USD comercial =',"R$",data )

response = requests.get('http://dolarhoje.com/dolar-turismo/cotacao.txt')
data = response.text
print('1 USD turismo =',"R$",data )

response = requests.get('http://dolarhoje.com/euro/cotacao.txt')
data2 = response.text
print('1 EUR comercial =',"R$",data2 )

response = requests.get('http://dolarhoje.com/euro-turismo/cotacao.txt')
data2 = response.text
print('1 EUR turismo =',"R$",data2 )

response = requests.get('http://dolarhoje.com/bitcoin-hoje/cotacao.txt')
data3 = response.text
print('1 BTC =',"R$",data3 )


current = time.strftime("ano:%Y dia:%d mês:%m horário:%H:%M:%S")
with open('cota.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.writelines('Valor euro turismo:' + 'R$' + data2 + ' ' + 'Data:' + current + '\n')
```

---

indicator.py

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


url = 'https://br.investing.com/currencies/eur-brl-technical'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
page
page.status_code
page.text
soup = bs(page.text, 'html.parser')
resumo = soup.find_all(id='techStudiesInnerWrap')[0].get_text(' ')
print(resumo)
```

---

invest.py

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


url = 'https://br.investing.com/currencies/eur-brl-technical'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
page
page.status_code
page.text
soup = bs(page.text, 'html.parser')
resumo = soup.find_all('div', class_="top bold inlineblock")[0].get_text(' ')
print(resumo)
```

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem! Here is the solution I've found:

First, you can visit the app here: [finance-python.herokuapp.com](https://finance-python.herokuapp.com/)

app.py

```py
from flask import Flask
from functools import wraps
import sqlite3
import requests
import bs4
import requests_html
from flask import render_template
import subprocess
import re
import flask
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    url = 'https://www.remessaonline.com.br/cotacao/cotacao-euro'
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    page
    page.status_code
    page.text
    soup = bs(page.text, 'html.parser')
    resumo = soup.find_all('div', class_="style__Text-sc-27fg4f-2 ddwOcG")[0].get_text('')
    mult = float(re.sub('[^0-9.]', "", resumo.replace(",",".")))
    euro_comercial_rem = print('Euro COMERCIAL: R$', mult)
    eur_rate = 1.035145
    eur_ra = str(mult * eur_rate)[:6]
    euro_turismo_rem = print('Euro TURISMO: R$', eur_ra)
    current = time.strftime("%Y / dia:%d mês:%m horário:%H:%M:%S")
    print(current)

    response = requests.get('http://dolarhoje.com/cotacao.txt')
    data = response.text
    dolar_com_dolar_hoje = print('1 USD comercial =',"R$",data )
    response = requests.get('http://dolarhoje.com/dolar-turismo/cotacao.txt')
    dataa = response.text
    dolar_tur_dolar_hoje = print('1 USD turismo =',"R$",dataa )

    response = requests.get('http://dolarhoje.com/euro/cotacao.txt')
    data2 = response.text
    euro_com_dolar_hoje = print('1 EUR comercial =',"R$",data2 )
    response = requests.get('http://dolarhoje.com/euro-turismo/cotacao.txt')
    dataa2 = response.text
    euro_tur_dolar_hoje = print('1 EUR turismo =',"R$",dataa2 )

    response = requests.get('http://dolarhoje.com/bitcoin-hoje/cotacao.txt')
    data3 = response.text
    btc_dolar_hoje = print('1 BTC =',"R$",data3 )


    current = time.strftime("ano:%Y dia:%d mês:%m horário:%H:%M:%S")

    url = 'https://br.investing.com/currencies/eur-brl-technical'
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    page
    page.status_code
    page.text
    soup = bs(page.text, 'html.parser')
    resumoo = soup.find_all(id='techStudiesInnerWrap')[0].get_text(' ')
    resumo_inves = print(resumoo)

    url = 'https://br.investing.com/currencies/eur-brl-technical'
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    page
    page.status_code
    page.text
    soup = bs(page.text, 'html.parser')
    resumooo = soup.find_all('div', class_="top bold inlineblock")[0].get_text(' ')
    resumo_invest_eur_brl = print(resumooo)
    #resumos = 'eur_ra' + 'euro_turismo_rem' + 'dolar_com_dolar_hoje' + 'dolar_tur_dolar_hoje' + 'btc_dolar_hoje' + 'resumo_inves' + 'euro_com_dolar_hoje' + 'euro_tur_dolar_hoje'

    return flask.render_template('index.html', mult=mult, eur_ra=eur_ra, current=current, data=data, dataa=dataa, data2=data2, dataa2=dataa2, data3=data3, resumoo=resumoo, resumooo=resumooo)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

index.html into *template* folder

```html
-----EURO DO REMESSA ONLINE----- <br>
EURO COMERCIAL : R$ {{ mult }} <br>
EURO TURISMO: R$ {{ eur_ra }} <br>
{{ current }} <br> <br>
----COTAÇÃO DOLARHOJE.COM----- <br>
1 USD comercial = R$ {{ data }} <br>
1 USD turismo = R$ {{ dataa }} <br>
1 EUR comercial = R$ {{ data2 }} <br>
1 EUR turismo = R$ {{ dataa2 }} <br>
1 BTC = R$ {{ data3 }} <br> <br>
-----INDICADOR EURO COMERCIAL H1----- <br>
{{ resumoo }} <br> <br>
-----VARIAÇÃO DO EURO-----<br>
{{ resumooo }} <br> <br>

Conhece a ti mesmo - Tales de Mileto
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can be helpful, and I don't know much about Python. But it sounds like if you're doing Server-side rendering of the html page, you just need a template engine such as Jade, Pug, or something of that sort.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples for you to follow :

https://www.grizzlypeaksoftware.com/articles?id=1m3W3llyJLy4YS5OpyyxBq

https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-flask-a-python-microframework

https://scoutapm.com/blog/python-flask-tutorial-getting-started-with-flask

https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/getting-started-with-flask/

https://github.com/akibrhast/flask_base_template

Basically what you need to learn about is how to create a backend server. In this case using flask. The templating engine that is typically used with flask is called Jinja. Once you make your request call to your data you would want to pass it through to your routes via jinja.

Here is a basic example:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, abort,url_for
import os

#from flask_login import login_user, current_user, logout_user, login_required #Optional login imports, need to 'pip install flask_login'

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template("base.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = os.urandom(12)
    app.run(debug=True)
```